# compute the ranking of a parameter in the list

Tags: prolog

My problem is how to write a program 'ranking(List, Item, rank)',
which given a List and Item will compute the list Indices, the list of integers N such that Item is the Nth item of the list List. For example:

```
ranking([a,b,c,d,d,c,b,a], a, Rank)    Rank= [1,8] 
ranking([a,b,c,d,d,c,b,a], b, Rank)    Rank = [2,7]
ranking([a,b,c,d,d,c,b,a], c, Rank)    Rank = [3,6] 
ranking([a,b,c,d,d,c,b,a], e, Rank)    Rank = []
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
ranking([E|_], E, 1).
ranking([_|T], E, I) :- ranking(T, E, I2), I is I2 + 1.
```

What I got:

```
ranking([a,b,c,a,d], a, R).
R = 1 ? ;
R = 4 ? ;
```

I don't know how to collect the positions and put them into a List.
just like: 
    R =[1,4].

Comment: Daniel Lyons ok, thank you

Comment: So, in your base case, the third argument is a list `[1]`, but in your inductive case, you are assigning it a value. You really need a separate argument to keep track of your index in the list, and you need another clause to handle items that do not match. You probably need to separate this into two predicates, `ranking/3` that calls `ranking_loop/4` with an index variable you can use and increment before recurring.

Comment: @Daniel Lyons  ,yeah thank you very much.

Comment: @DanielLyons, i have think a lot , but I don't know how to collect the positions and put them into a List. just like: R =[1,4].

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to be patient, and not leave comments like "would you please help me?" You are already receiving help from the people who can help, at the speed they can. Please remember we are volunteers, many of us contribute only after work. We do want to help you learn! But we cannot be held to replying within any particular amount of time.

Comment: @DanielLyons ok ,i' m sorry. i'm new here. i will be more patient later.

Comment: it's OK! We were all new once.

Comment: @DanielLyons hi,Daniel. I sent another email to you.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [findall](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3)/3 and [nth1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth1/3)/3 builtins:

```erlang
ranking(Es,E,Rs) :- findall(I,nth1(I,Es,E),Rs).
```

Comment: however, in my eclipse i use sicstus prolog, the return is :                                 ?- ranking([a,b,a],a,R).
! Existence error in user:nth1/3
! procedure user:nth1/3 does not exist
! goal:  user:nth1(_323,[a,b,a],a)
% source_info

Comment: nth1/3 is in library(lists). SWI-Prolog autoloads it, guess SICSTUS Prolog requires you to explicitly load it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not stop when you found the first element, since it is still possible that other items match.

It is probably easier to use an *accumulator* here. A variable that first is `1` for example, and each time you make a next step in the list, you pass an incremented copy.

```
ranking(L, X, R) :-
    ranking(L, X, 1, R).
```

Now we can see three cases:

1. in case the list is empty, the list of indices is empty as well;
2. in case the list is not empty and the first element matches with the item we search for, we add the accumulator to the result and recurse on the lists; and
3. in case the list is not empty and the first element does not matches, we recurse on the list.

For example:

```
ranking([], _, _, []).
ranking([H|T], H2, K, [K|KT]) :-
    H == H2,
    K1 is K+1,
    ranking(T, H2, K1, KT).
ranking([H|T], H2, K, KT) :-
    dif(H, H2),
    K1 is K+1,
    ranking(T, H2, K1, KT).
```

Comment: I'd like to do something like this:

findAll([a,b,c,a,d], a, R).
R = [1, 4]

Comment: @zha did you forget to include the two lines in the first code block? Taken together with the block at the bottom, it works the way you expect.